# How to run different recipes for different sets of dependencies of the same target file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Make manual says I can have only one recipe per target. But I need to run different building tools depending on which dependencies has changed.

Something like this:

```
target.txt: subtarget.txt
    cat $? >> $@

target.txt: header.txt
    date >>$@
```

Is there some trick to archive it?

Comment: Much better, in general, is to (re)build each required target appropriately from scratch, from *all* its prerequisites, whenever it is out of date.  If you do this then you do not need multiple recipes.  If you cannot structure it that way, then POSIX `make` has no solution for you, though you might be able to achieve it by use of extensions provided by various specific `make` implementations.

Comment: Good point - rebuilding from scratch would be elegant. Unfortunately, it would be very ineffective in my case. I had a solution with loops in `makefile` and shell scripts with logic detecting a type of dependency and running appropriate update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but maybe [double-colon rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Double_002dColon.html) will help you?

```
target.txt:: subtarget.txt
        cat $? >> $@

target.txt:: header.txt
         date >>$@
```

Comment: That sounds like what the OP asked for.  Of course, it is an extension to POSIX `make`, but it seems to be supported fairly widely.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The question was tagged `gnu-make` so I just assumed :)

Comment: A reasonable assumption, to be sure, but I think it's important when people use an extension for them to do so knowingly and intentionally.  GNU `make` doesn't rule the world (yet), and it really sucks when you have trouble using that cool, shiny, new toy because of careless compatibility issues.